# Regex working on regexpal but not with Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regex to catch email Ids . Testing since quite a few hours using regexpal.com . On the site, its able to catch all the email Ids. WHen I am substituting the same regex in Python and doing re.findall(pattern,line), it is not able to catch it.

Regex :

```
[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+[(.)?a-zA-Z0-9-_]*\s*(@|at)\s*[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\s*(.|dot)\s*[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*\s*(.|dot)\s*e(\-)?d(\-)?u(\-)?(.,)?
```

Example :

```
Line =    <TR> <TD><B>E-Mail: </B> <TD><A HREF=MailTo:*example.young@stackoverflow.edu*\>*example.young@stackoverflow.edu*</A>
```

(Highlighted correctly on regexpal.com).

With Python :

```
 for line in f:
    print 'Line = ',line
        matches = re.findall(my_first_pat,line)
    print 'Matches = ',matches
```

Gives output:

```
Line =    <TR> <TD><B>E-Mail: </B> <TD><A HREF=MailTo:example.young@stackoverflow.edu>example.young@stackoverflow.edu</A>

Matches =  [('@', 'd', '.', '', '', '', ''), ('@', 'd', '.', '', '', '', '')]
```

What is the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall) for `re.findall`:

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups

Your groups only capture the at sign, dot, etc., therefore that's all that's returned by re.findall.  Either use non-capturing groups, wrap the whole thing in a group, or use `re.finditer`.

(As noted by @Igor Chubin, your regex is also incorrectly using `.` instead of `\.`, but this isn't causing the main problem.)

Comment: Can you explain how do I use non-capturing groups or , wrap the whole thing in a group?

Comment: For info on that, check out just about any regex tutorial or reference, for instance http://www.regular-expressions.info/ .

Answer (score 0):

You must use `\.` not `.` here:

```
(.|dot)
```

If you just want to say that you can have hyphens between letters 
in the `edu` part, you can do this without slashes and grouping:

```
e-?d-?u-?[.,]?
```

If you use `()` just to group symbols (but not for capturing), 
you must use `(?:)`instead:

```
(?:@|at)
```

Comment: This e(\-)? , I Used it in case an email is of the form a-b-c-@-d-e-f-.e-d-u .