# strange behavior of parenthesis in python regex

Tags: python, regex, quotes, parentheses, backreference

I'm writing a python regex that looks through a text document for quoted strings (quotes of airline pilots recorded from blackboxes).  I started by trying to write a regex with the following rules:

Return what is between quotes.
*if it opens with single, only return if it closes with single.

 if it opens with double, only return if it closes with double.*

For instance I don't want to match "hi there', or 'hi there", but "hi there" and 'hi there'.

I use a testing page which contains things like:

```
CA  "Runway 18, wind 230 degrees, five knots, altimeter 30."
AA  "Roger that"
18:24:10 [flap lever moving into detent]
ST: "Some passenger's pushing a switch. May I?"
```

So I decided to start simple:

```
 re.findall('("|\').*?\\1', page)
 ########## /("|').*?\1/ <-- raw regex I think I'm going for.
```

This regex acts very unexpectedly.
I thought it would:

1. ( " | " ) Match EITHER single OR double quotes, save as back reference /1.
2. .*? Match non-greedy wildcard.
3. \1 Match whatever it finds in back reference \1 (step one).

Instead, it returns an array of quotes but never anything else.

```
['"', '"', "'", "'"]
```

I'm really confused because the equivalent (afaik) regex works just fine in VIM.

```
\("\|'\).\{-}\1/)
```

My question is this:
Why does it return only what is inside parenthesis as the match?  Is this a flaw in my understanding of back references?  If so then why does it work in VIM?

And how do I write the regex I'm looking for in python?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall).  `re.findall` returns the groups, if there are any.  If you want the entire match you must group it all, or use `re.finditer`.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11663995/regex-working-on-regexpal-but-not-with-python/11664124#11664124).

Comment: The documentation still didn't make sense to me because I figured groups meant potential matches, not control groups.  Thank you for clearing that up.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't capturing anything except for the quotes, which is what Python is returning.

If you add another group, things work much better:

```
for quote, match in re.finditer(r'("|\')(.*?)\1', page):
  print match
```

I prefixed your string literal with an `r` to make it a *raw* string, which is useful when you need to use a ton of backslashes (`\\1` becomes `\1`).

Comment: Great!  But does this mean that if part of the expression is in a control group everything else has to be in a control group as well?

Comment: The things inside of a matching group are the things that are returned when you search with the regex. If you want the whole regex to match, you wrap everything in a group.

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch everything with an extra pair of parentheses.

```
re.findall('(("|\').*?\\2)', page)
```